# How to set parameterized title on Stack.screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I need a help on following code

```
<Stack.Screen name="UserDetails" 
              component={UserDetails} 
              options={{title : 'User',headerStyle: { backgroundColor: '#990000',},headerTintColor: '#fff',}}
/>
```

I have to put dynamic title value from

```
options={({ route }) => ({ title: route.params.name })}
```

How to set it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: i guess you mean that you don't know how to combine them all together? dynamic title, headerStyle etc?

Comment: or do you want to know how to pass parameters to screen?

Answer (score 1):

You could set it using the following code:

```
<Stack.Screen
    name="Profile"
    component={ProfileScreen}
    options={({ route }) => ({ title: route.params.name })}
/>
```

Here is a link to a [working example](https://snack.expo.io/?platform=android&name=params%20in%20title&dependencies=%40react-native-community%2Fmasked-view%40%5E0.1.7%2C%40react-navigation%2Fbottom-tabs%40%5E5.7.0%2C%40react-navigation%2Fdrawer%40%5E5.8.5%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-bottom-tabs%40%5E5.2.13%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-top-tabs%40%5E5.2.13%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative%40%5E5.7.0%2C%40react-navigation%2Fstack%40%5E5.7.0%2Creact-native-paper%40%5E3.10.1%2Creact-native-reanimated%40%5E1.7.0%2Creact-native-safe-area-context%40%5E3.0.2%2Creact-native-screens%40%5E2.9.0%2Creact-native-tab-view%40%5E2.14.0&sourceUrl=https%3A%2F%2Freactnavigation.org%2Fexamples%2F5.x%2Fparams-in-title.js).

The example is from the docs link - https://reactnavigation.org/docs/headers/#using-params-in-the-title

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to pass parameters to a screen?

Like so:

```
navigation.navigate('UserDetails', {name: 'JohnDoe'});
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params

Comment: hmm yes, now that i read the post again, i guess this is what the user wants to do.